# Wordpress run php-script that adds dynamic shortcodes to a page before load

Tags: php, wordpress, dom

I have a script that loops through a JSON-datafile and from that file creates dynamically shortcodes that I want to be loaded in a spesific Wordpress page. The script loads different JSON-files depending on the logged in users ID.

the shortcodes look like this after processing:

```
[woocommerce_product_documents product_sku="70.2991" title="nozzle for Adheseal"]
[woocommerce_product_documents product_sku="70.0900" title="Spraygun Multiflexcoating"]
[woocommerce_product_documents product_sku="70.2901" title="Spraygun Nozzle Coating."]
```

When manually added to a WP page the shortcodes are executed as normal. What I am trying to figure out is how to add/update the page dynamically, when the customer requests it. a.k.a run the script and get updated information from the JSON-file.

I know I can set a condition for the script to run on spesific conditions. But I haven't figured out how to make WP execute the shortcodes before the page is loaded. as if they were already there ?

If there is an answer to this question somewhere that I have missed, please send me a link.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don’t have a solution, but I’m pretty sure you _don’t_ want the shortcodes to execute “before the page is loaded”, but instead you want it to be rendered at a very specific spot on the page, right? Your first task is to then determine where this specific spot is, sidebar, header, body, “between A and B”, etc., and from there you can either tweak the theme, use the hook system, or possibly create your own shortcode like `xander_dynamic_products` so that content authors can place this exactly where needed.

Comment: the page is a blank page that will open inside a template. And the shortcodes created comes with preprogrammed CSS. So all I need is to update the page before it is loaded into the dom.